# Infinite sections in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I'm trying to figure out how to have infinite sections in a collection view.  I don't want to 'wrap around' which is what most of the infinite scrolling posts are about.

I'm thinking something more like a calendar, for example, where if your section is the year then it can just go forward or backwards (almost) forever.

Where I'm confused is what I would return for numberOfSections method, for example.  I know there are some existing controls that do this, but I'm trying to do this as a learning thing so just grabbing a huge block of code and trying to parse it isn't so easy.

I'm targeting iOS 10 if that changes your answer any.

Comment: Why would you want a collection view that goes forever? There has to be some limit right? Even if you are trying to create a calendar (like the one i made), you can set a limit to be say 20 years. But there is a limit.

Comment: There doesn't have to be a limit if you do it right.  There are others out there that do it already.  You've gotta munge the data source, chagne the scroll position, reload, etc....